# Objective C import circle logic. Init Methods confusion. Music Library

Tags: objective-c

I'm starting out with Objective-C and I'm doing an exercise on a MusicCollection and Playlists. The MusicCollection has a master Playlist which will contain all the songs contained in the other playlists. I don't want to allow the user to create a playlist without it being added to a music library immediately. This way, a user can create a playlist and then just add songs to it immediately and it will be reflected in the master library without having to add it manually later. So here's my init in MusicCollection:

```
- (id) initWithName: (NSString *)aName
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        name = aName;                             // name of MusicCollection
        collection = [NSMutableArray array];      // array of Playlist objects

        // Now I'm making a playlist which I want to be designated
        // as the master playlist.

        library = [[Playlist alloc] initWithName:@"Library"
                                 underCollection:self];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Now I'm not sure of the logic to do in the Playlist init method. I don't want to allow the user to create a Playlist object if there is not yet a proper MusicCollection created. Here's what I have:

```
- (id) initWithName: (NSString *)theName underCollection:(MusicCollection *)theMusic
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        name = theName;
        songs = [NSMutableArray array];

        if([theMusic.collection count] == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"This is the master playlist");
            [theMusic.collection addObject:self];
        }
        else if([theMusic.collection count] != 0)
        {
            [theMusic.collection addObject:self];
             NSLog(@"Adding a regular playlist");
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

This seems risky to me. Like a user can just try to create a playlist with some MusicCollection that's not properly initialized by just calling the init method on Playlist. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may override `-init` in your `Playlist` class:

```
- (id)init
{
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException reason:@"Use -initWithName:underCollection: instead" userInfo:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hm. I guess that should work! I think I was just thinking too much. I guess I don't even need the if statements. I can just use logic elsewhere that uses the master playlist as the first index.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the init method of playlist and add these checks, or have it throw an exception so that init cannot be used to make a playlist.